# Unable to connect to MongoDB server using x509 certificate authentication from c#

Tags: mongodb, ssl, mongodb-.net-driver, x509certificate2

I have configured MongoDB server as given in document https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/security-x.509/
and I connected using mongo shell it is working fine.

Next I tried to connect to same server form c# driver, but Time out exception raised.
Below is my code

```
var cert = new X509Certificate2(@"C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.2\ssl\client.pfx", "secretkey");
            var sslcrd = MongoCredential.CreateMongoX509Credential("CN=Client1,O=School,ST=Some-State,C=IN");
            settings.SslSettings = new SslSettings() ; 
            settings.UseSsl = true;
            settings.SslSettings.ClientCertificates = new List<X509Certificate>()
    {
        cert
    };
            settings.SslSettings.EnabledSslProtocols = SslProtocols.Default;
            settings.SslSettings.ClientCertificateSelectionCallback =
                (sender, host, certificates, certificate, issuers) => settings.SslSettings.ClientCertificates.ToList()[0];
            settings.SslSettings.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (sender, certificate, chain, errors) => true;
            settings.SslSettings.CheckCertificateRevocation = false;
            settings.VerifySslCertificate = false;
            settings.Credentials = new[] { sslcrd };

            MongoClient client = new MongoClient(settings);
            var db = client.ListDatabases().ToList();
```

I went through MongoDB server logs and I am able to see below error

> 2017-04-10T11:18:21.559+0530 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection
>   accepted from
>    127.0.0.1:53901 #64 (1 connection now open) 2017-04-10T11:18:21.559+0530 E NETWORK  [conn64] no SSL certificate
>   provided by peer; connection rejected 2017-04-10T11:18:21.560+0530 I
>   NETWORK  [conn64] end connection 127.0.0.1:53901 (0 connections now
>   open)

I am using c# MongoDB.Driver version 2.3.0
and MongoDB package is of version 3.2.

If you have solution for the above please do reply.

Answer (score 0):

In despite of this thread be a little bit old, I faced this exactly same issue today and found a solution at MongoDB.com site (Setup Connection Security code example), so,sharing the solution here for future searchs.

Basically the settings should be created from a connection string and follow the next steps straightforward:

```
using MongoDB.Bson;
using MongoDB.Driver;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MainAsync().Wait();
    }
    static async Task MainAsync()
    {
        var connectionString = "mongodb+srv://<your-server.mongodb.net>/?authSource=%24external&authMechanism=MONGODB-X509&retryWrites=true&w=majority";
        var settings = MongoClientSettings.FromConnectionString(connectionString);
        settings.ServerApi = new ServerApi(ServerApiVersion.V1);
        // You will need to convert your Atlas-provided PEM containing the cert/private keys into a PFX
        // use openssl and the following line to create a PFX from your PEM:
        // openssl pkcs12 -export -in <x509>.pem -inkey <x509>.pem -out <x509>.pfx
        // and provide a password, which should match the second argument you pass to X509Certificate2
        var cert = new X509Certificate2("<path_to_pfx>", "<pfx_passphrase>");
        settings.SslSettings = new SslSettings
        {
            ClientCertificates = new List<X509Certificate>(){ cert }
        };
        var client = new MongoClient(settings);
        var database = client.GetDatabase("testDB");
        var collection = database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("testCol");
        var docCount = collection.CountDocuments("{}");
        Console.WriteLine(docCount);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Set the value of `allowConnectionsWithoutCertificates` to false. Also, you need to combine the certificate and the key file.

Comment: Hi Mahdi,

I set above property in Mongo server, I am facing the error, "2017-04-10T16:09:33.171+0530 I ACCESS   [conn49] Failed to authenticate CN=Client1,O=School,ST=Some-State,C=IN@$external with mechanism MONGODB-X509: AuthenticationFailed: There is no x.509 client certificate matching the user."

Comment: Also In mongo shell we should specify CA pem file also while starting it, but in c# I didnt specify CA pem file(I didn't find any api to specify it), is there any api to specify CA file ?